# Performing VIF Test in R

Tags: r, plm

I started using R studio a few days ago and I am struggling a bit to compute a VIF. Here is the situation:

I have a panel data and ran Fixed effect and Random effect regressions. I have one Dependent Variable (`New_biz_density`) and 2 Independent variables (`Cost_to_start`, `Capital_requirements`). I would like to check if my two independent variables present multicollinearity by computing their Variance Inflation Factor, both for Fixed and Random effect models.

I already installed some packages to perform the VIF (`Faraway`, `Car`) but did not manage to do it. Does anybody know how to do it?

Here is my script:

```
# install.packages("plm")
library(plm)

mydata<- read.csv("/Users/juliantabone/Downloads/DATAweakoutliers.csv")


Y <- cbind(new_biz_density)
X <- cbind(capital_requirements, cost_to_start)

# Set data as panel data
pdata <- plm.data(mydata, index=c("country_code","year"))

# Descriptive statistics
summary(Y)
summary(X)

# Pooled OLS estimator
pooling <- plm(Y ~ X, data=pdata, model= "pooling")
summary(pooling)

# Between estimator
between <- plm(Y ~ X, data=pdata, model= "between")
summary(between)

# First differences estimator
firstdiff <- plm(Y ~ X, data=pdata, model= "fd")
summary(firstdiff)

# Fixed effects or within estimator
fixed <- plm(Y ~ X, data=pdata, model= "within")
summary(fixed)

# Random effects estimator
random <- plm(Y ~ X, data=pdata, model= "random")
summary(random)

# LM test for random effects versus OLS
plmtest(pooling)

# LM test for fixed effects versus OLS
pFtest(fixed, pooling)

# Hausman test for fixed versus random effects model
phtest(random, fixed)
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two popular ways of calculating VIFs (Variance Inflation Factors, to detect collinearity among variables in regression) in R:

The `vif()` function in the `car` package, where the input is the model. This requires you to first fit a model before you can check for VIFs among variables in the model.

The `corvif()` function, where the input are the actual candidate explanatory variables (i.e. a list of variables, before the model is even fitted). This function is part of the `AED` package (Zuur et al. 2009), which has been discontinued. This one seems to work only on a list of variables, not on a fitted regression model.

Answer (score 0):

To compute VIF refer function `non_collinear_vars` from `metan` package.

To compute the VIF between two variables `Cost_to_start` & `Capital_requirements` use,

```
library(metan)
non_collinear_vars(X)
```